# Alterar quantidade de dígitos após a vírgula dependendo da situação

Tags: c, formatação, float, printf, double

Sei que posso obter um limite de dígitos após a vírgula com `%.2f` para `float` e `%.2lf` para `double`.

Como posso modificar esse limite dependendo da ocasião?

Por exemplo:

Obter um limite de dois dígitos com `float` que seria `%.2f`, ou seja, se o número for `310.22`, o mesmo aparecerá - mas, se o número acabar em zero, diminuir esse limite: no caso de `310.10`, ficaria `310.1` (sendo que os números irão variar).

Ao compilar a programação abaixo com `16` e `455` o resultado será de `436.10`, mas quero mostrá-lo como `436.1`, sem modificar os outros resultados que, caso não se finalizem com zero, tenham duas casas decimais.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double d,km,km2,v,k;
    scanf("%lf%lf",&d,&km);
    v=d*30;
    km2=km*0.01;
    v=v+km2;
    k=v*0.10;
    v=v-k;
    printf("\n%.2lf",v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Tem que usar o `%g`. Veja [todas formatações possíveis](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%g\n", 310.0);
    printf("%g\n", 310.1);
    printf("%g\n", 310.12);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/n09xbo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rlijyjoc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/DecimalPlacesVariable.c).

Comment: %g não está funcionando do jeito que queria, já que os números iram variar, viram em um scanf e serão armazenados em um variável tipo float ou Double e não um numero em particular. Mesmo com uma variável %g não funcionará e mesmo modificando para %.5g por exemplo o valor não seria aceitavel porque modificaria também os números antes da vírgula.

Comment: Você não colocou isso na sua pergunta, eu respondi baseado no que você perguntou e mostrei que de acordo com o que está na sua pergunta, funciona. Você pode fazer uma outra pergunta colocando o seu código real e o que está dando errado e o que deveria ser o certo, nesta aqui já foi respondido o que foi perguntado.